# Why does my onTouch Listener for the views make them go left and top when I click to the left and above the view?

Tags: android, android-view

I am making an Android app, I have to drag a view of a LinearLayout into the main container RelativeLayout, then again I set an OnTouchListener for that view after adding it to RelativeLayout, the problem is that after being added the view behaves improperly, **I mean if I touch to the left or top of the view the view moves to left or top, now that shouldnt happen.**

I have been trying to find a reason as of why the views behave so badly, but couldn't figure of a single reason, can someone please help me out here,

**Here is my code....**

```
public class MovingViewsActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    int i = 0;
    Button btn;
    private Button btn1, btn2, btn3;
    private RelativeLayout layout;
    private LayoutParams params;
    List<ImageView> imgList;
    private ImageView image;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        imgList = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);
        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn2.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn3.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        btn.setOnTouchListener(this);
        btn1.setOnTouchListener(this);
        btn2.setOnTouchListener(this);
        btn3.setOnTouchListener(this);

    }

    OnTouchListener dragit = new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v
                    .getLayoutParams();

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                params.topMargin = (int) event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight()) - 30;
                params.leftMargin = (int) event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()) + 30;
                v.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
            v.invalidate();
            return true;

        }

    };

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            i++;
            image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            image.setImageBitmap(btn1.getDrawingCache());
            image.setId(i);
            image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            layout.addView(image, params);
            imgList.add(image);
            Log.d("Number of VIEWS", "Number of VIEWS " + imgList.size()
                    + " ID: " + image.getId());
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            int left = (int) event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth() / 2);
            int top = (int) event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight());
            image.setPadding(left, top, 0, 0);

            image.invalidate();

        }
        for (ImageView img : imgList) {

            img.setOnTouchListener(dragit);

        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure how you want to move your layout, but if you wanted to make it so that the center of your layout is in the middle of your finger you'd need to

```
params.TopMargin -= (int) event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight()/2) 
params.LeftMargin -= (int) event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2)
```

Also, I would say handle the dragit onTouchlistener like your onTouch method.

Create a RelativeLayout DragLayer in your ACTION_DOWN case and then handle that Layer in your ACTION_MOVE case

There are some good example in how to do this [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)(android documentation) and [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html)(third party example)